# Can I rely on the key order of a JavaScript object literal that's never written to?

Tags: javascript, object

I understand that in JS Object keys aren't guaranteed to be ordered.

However, I find that for object literals the order, after creation, remains equal to the literal unless I add a new key.

Could I rely on the key ordering of an object literal I freeze?

For instance:

```
const o = Object.freeze({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
});
```

What are the conditions under which the order of this object's keys **wouldn't be** a,b,c?

Comment: In ES6+, keys are guaranteed to be ordered in (1) numeric index order (2) insertion order

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do but it is a pretty bad idea to rely on key order.

Comment: CertainPerformance: I understand there are very similar questions, but I don't think the specific thing I'm asking has been asked before on SO. Please reconsider.